# DNA subsequence dynamic programming question

Tags: algorithm, subsequence, lcs

I'm trying to solve DNA problem which is more of improved(?) version of LCS problem. 
In the problem, there is string which is string and semi-substring which allows part of string to have one or no letter skipped. For example, for string "desktop", it has semi-substring `{"destop", "dek", "stop", "skop","desk","top"}`, all of which has one or no letter skipped.

Now, I am given two DNA strings consisting of `{a,t,g,c}`. I"m trying to find longest semi-substring, LSS. and if there is more than one LSS, print out the one in the fastest order.

For example, two dnas `{attgcgtagcaatg, tctcaggtcgatagtgac}` prints out `"tctagcaatg"`

and `aaaattttcccc, cccgggggaatatca` prints out `"aattc"`

I'm trying to use common LCS algorithm but cannot solve it with tables although I did solve the one with no letter skipped. Any advice?

Comment: Did you mean you'd like to find the longest _common_ semi-substring?

Comment: "aattc" is not a semi-substring of "aaaattttcccc". Is there a typo somewhere?

Comment: By the way, I think the acronym, "LCS," is typically associated with the longest common subsequence problem, which has no restriction on the number of skipped letters.

Comment: Can you skip multiple times?  That is, is `dstp` an allowed LSS of `desktop`?  I ask because your description doesn't make it clear, but your examples make it seem needed.

Comment: I don't see how this example you gave is only allowing one skipped letter -  `{attgcgtagcaatg, tctcaggtcgatagtgac} prints out "tctagcaatg"`

Comment: sorry. It allows one or zero skipped letter in multiple occurences.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying. My new answer returns `ttcgtgaatg` for the first example, `attgcgtagcaatg, tctcaggtcgatagtgac`. Both seem valid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a variation on the dynamic programming solution for LCS, written in Python.

First I'm building up a [Suffix Tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Suffix_tree) for all the substrings that can be made from each string with the skip rule.  Then I'm intersecting the suffix trees.  Then I'm looking for the longest string that can be made from that intersection tree.

Please note that this is technically `O(n^2)`.  Its worst case is when both strings are the same character, repeated over and over again.  Because you wind up with a lot of what logically is something like, "an 'l' at position 42 in the one string could have matched against position `l` at position 54 in the other".  But in practice it will be `O(n)`.

```
def find_subtree (text, max_skip=1):
    tree = {}
    tree_at_position = {}

    def subtree_from_position (position):
        if position not in tree_at_position:
            this_tree = {}
            if position < len(text):
                char = text[position]
                # Make sure that we've populated the further tree.
                subtree_from_position(position + 1)

                # If this char appeared later, include those possible matches.
                if char in tree:
                    for char2, subtree in tree[char].iteritems():
                        this_tree[char2] = subtree

                # And now update the new choices.
                for skip in range(max_skip + 1, 0, -1):
                    if position + skip < len(text):
                        this_tree[text[position + skip]] = subtree_from_position(position + skip)

                tree[char] = this_tree

            tree_at_position[position] = this_tree

        return tree_at_position[position]

    subtree_from_position(0)

    return tree


def find_longest_common_semistring (text1, text2):
    tree1 = find_subtree(text1)
    tree2 = find_subtree(text2)

    answered = {}
    def find_intersection (subtree1, subtree2):
        unique = (id(subtree1), id(subtree2))
        if unique not in answered:
            answer = {}
            for k, v in subtree1.iteritems():
                if k in subtree2:
                    answer[k] = find_intersection(v, subtree2[k])
            answered[unique] = answer
        return answered[unique]


    found_longest = {}
    def find_longest (tree):
        if id(tree) not in found_longest:
            best_candidate = ''
            for char, subtree in tree.iteritems():
                candidate = char + find_longest(subtree)
                if len(best_candidate) < len(candidate):
                    best_candidate = candidate
            found_longest[id(tree)] = best_candidate
        return found_longest[id(tree)]

    intersection_tree = find_intersection(tree1, tree2)
    return find_longest(intersection_tree)


print(find_longest_common_semistring("attgcgtagcaatg", "tctcaggtcgatagtgac"))
```

Comment: Added a recursion based on mapped occurrences of the characters. Not sure if there could be any advantage (probably less :)

Comment: @NathanLee my previous version had a bug.  If the best answer needed to start at the second occurrence  of a character, it wasn't finding it.  My apologies, and the current version has fixed that.

Answer (score 1):

Let `g(c, rs, rt)` represent the longest common semi-substring of strings, `S` and `T`, ending at `rs` and `rt`, where `rs` and `rt` are the ranked occurences of the character, `c`, in `S` and `T`, respectively, and `K` is the number of skips allowed. Then we can form a recursion which we would be obliged to perform on all pairs of `c` in S and T.

JavaScript code:

```js
function f(S, T, K){
  // mapS maps a char to indexes of its occurrences in S
  // rsS maps the index in S to that char's rank (index) in mapS
  const [mapS, rsS] = mapString(S)
  const [mapT, rsT] = mapString(T)
  // h is used to memoize g
  const h = {}

  function g(c, rs, rt){
    if (rs < 0 || rt < 0)
      return 0
    
    if (h.hasOwnProperty([c, rs, rt]))
      return h[[c, rs, rt]]
      
    // (We are guaranteed to be on
    // a match in this state.)
    let best = [1, c]
    
    let idxS = mapS[c][rs]
    let idxT = mapT[c][rt]

    if (idxS == 0 || idxT == 0)
      return best

    for (let i=idxS-1; i>=Math.max(0, idxS - 1 - K); i--){
      for (let j=idxT-1; j>=Math.max(0, idxT - 1 - K); j--){
        if (S[i] == T[j]){
          const [len, str] = g(S[i], rsS[i], rsT[j])

          if (len + 1 >= best[0])
            best = [len + 1, str + c]
        }
      }
    }
  
    return h[[c, rs, rt]] = best
  }

  let best = [0, '']
  
  for (let c of Object.keys(mapS)){
    for (let i=0; i<(mapS[c]||[]).length; i++){
      for (let j=0; j<(mapT[c]||[]).length; j++){
        let [len, str] = g(c, i, j)
        
        if (len > best[0])
          best = [len, str]
      }
    }
  }
  
  return best
}

function mapString(s){
  let map = {}
  let rs = []
  
  for (let i=0; i<s.length; i++){
    if (!map[s[i]]){
      map[s[i]] = [i]
      rs.push(0)
    
    } else {
      map[s[i]].push(i)
      rs.push(map[s[i]].length - 1)
    }
  }
  
  return [map, rs]
}

console.log(f('attgcgtagcaatg', 'tctcaggtcgatagtgac', 1))

console.log(f('aaaattttcccc', 'cccgggggaatatca', 1))

console.log(f('abcade', 'axe', 1))
```

Comment: I was checking whether you had the same bug that I originally did, and stumbled over another one.  If you `console.log(f('abcade', 'axe', 1))` the code dies an interesting death.